# How to pull from origin using JGit on existing repository

Tags: java, git, jgit

I need a piece of code which can `pull` from origin and `merge` with local repo. I tried with local repo which can get the last commit and revision. however not able to `pull` the changes from origin.

```
File gitWorkDir = new File(gitDir);
Git git = Git.open(gitWorkDir);
Repository repo = git.getRepository();
UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider user = new 
UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("username", "password");
PullCommand pullCmd = git.pull();
pullCmd.setCredentialsProvider(user);
pullCmd.call();
ObjectId lastCommitId = repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
log.info(lastCommitId);
```

where `gitDir` is my local Repository Dir.

Comment: `git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(user).setRemote("origin").setRemoteBranchName("master").call();`?

Comment: thanks Mincong Huang :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I added some explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide the remote repository name, and the remote branche name. For example `origin` and `master`:

```
PullResult result = git.pull()
    .setCredentialsProvider(user)
    .setRemote("origin")
    .setRemoteBranchName("master")
    .call();

if (result.isSuccessful()) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Please also note that the result returned by the pull command is [`PullRequest`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PullResult.html)—its method `isSuccessful()` indicates whether the pull was successful. You might want to add this logic in your code too.

References:

- [Git - `git-pull` Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)
- [Javadoc `org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullResult`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PullResult.html)